# Golang:xml unmarshall not working as expected

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

response getting in xml format:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName</id>
<updated>2009-09-10T05:24:23.120Z</updated>
<title>Activity</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/system/app/pages/recentChanges"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed" type="application/atom+xml"
  href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName"/>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
  href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName"/>
<generator version="1" uri="http://sites.google.com">Google Sites</generator>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="W/&quot;CU4GQ3szfSl7ImA9WxNRFUg.&quot;">
<id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/940375996952876062</id>
<updated>2009-09-10T03:38:42.585Z</updated>
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#deletion" label="deletion"/>
<title>home</title>
<summary type="xhtml">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">User deleted <a href="http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/home">home</a>
</div>
</summary>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#revision" type="application/atom+xml"
  href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/revision/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#current" type="application/atom+xml"
  href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
  href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/940375996952876062"/>
<author>
  <name>User</name>
  <email>user@gmail.com</email>
</author>
</entry>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="W/&quot;CU8DQn45fyl7ImA9WxNRFUg.&quot;">
  <id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/7165439066235480082</id>
  <updated>2009-09-10T03:37:53.027Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#edit" label="edit"/>
  <title>home</title>
  <summary type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">User2 edited <a href="http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/home">home</a>
  </div>
  </summary>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#revision" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/revision/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#current" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/7165439066235480082"/>
  <author>
    <name>User</name>
    <email>user@gmail.com</email>
  </author>
</entry>
<entry xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" gd:etag="W/&quot;CU8AR3s4cSl7ImA9WxNRFUg.&quot;">
  <id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/127448462987345884</id>
  <updated>2009-09-10T03:37:26.539Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#creation" label="creation"/>
  <title>home</title>
  <summary type="xhtml">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">User3 created <a href="http://sites.google.com/site/siteName/home">home</a>
  </div>
  </summary>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#revision" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/revision/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#current" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/site/siteName/5409745539831916487"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/activity/site/siteName/127448462987345884"/>
  <author>
    <name>User3</name>
    <email>user3@gmail.com</email>
  </author>
</entry>
</feed>
```

In GO i using following structure and code to decode

```html
type XMLLink struct {
 XMLName xml.Name `xml:"link"`
 Rel     string   `xml:"rel,attr"`
 Href    string   `xml:"rel,href"`
}
type XMLEntry struct {
 XMLName xml.Name  `xml:"entry"`
 Link    []XMLLink `xml:"link,attr"`
}
type XMLFeed struct {
 XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"feed"`
 Entry   []XMLEntry `xml:"entry,attr"`
}
```

here i want to decode only link tag under entry tag.
following is the code i using to decode the xml into necessary values

```html
var feed XMLFeed
//response got from http request is expected xml here which is already men tioned above
bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
   err := xml.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &feed)
   if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to unmarshall", err)
   }
   fmt.Println("number of entries:", feed)
```

but here output is only
 **number of entries: {{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom feed} []}**
dont know what is going wrong here please suggest any changes to make this work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `attr` where you shouldn't.

You are treating the `XMLEntry` and `XMLLink` tags as attributes.